# Why is my expected output not happening?

Tags: c++

```
   /*This program will ask a user to enter a song list. By doing this each time that the user enters
a song, he/she will then be asked if they want to enter another song, if yes then they will enter another song.There will be a maximum of 15 songs.
This progarm will help a user keep track of their songs. But then the program will output the amount of songs, and what they are.
input:A song. Then a yes or no, if yes, another song, if no the program will output.
output:The number of songs, and then the songs themselves, each song with it's own individual line.
processing: There will be two functions, one of which will ask the user for the songs and store them, and another for which will be computing
the output.
*/
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>

    using namespace std;

    void input(string[15], int);
    void printArray(string[15], int);

    int main()
    {
    string songarray[15];
    int arraysize=15;
    int j=0;

    input(songarray, arraysize);

    int x=songarray[j].length();

    cout<<"There were "<<x<<" song titles entered.";
    printArray(songarray, x);
    return 0;
    }

/*This function will ask for the users input for a song and store the song in the songarray. He or she
will then be asked whether or not they want to enter another song, if so, then they will enter another song.
input:a song, y/Y or n/N for if they want to continue or not with another song
output:song will be sent to main function
processing: A while loop will be used for the user to enter is Y or N, and a for loop (while loop nested) for the user to enter the 
songs
*/
    void input(string titles[15], int rows)
    {

    char answer='y';

    for(int i=0;i<rows && (answer=='Y' || answer=='y');i++)
    {

        cout<<"Enter the name of a song. ";
        cin>>titles[i];
        cout<<"Do you want to continue (y/n)? ";
        cin>>answer;
    }
    }

/*The purpose of this function is to print the array from the main function.
input:accepts the array from the main function
output: prints the array
processing:nested loops will pring this array.
*/

    void printArray(string playlist[15], int quantity)
    {
    for(int j=0; j<quantity; j++)
    {
        cout<<playlist[j];
    }
    }
```

So the expected output is clear, where the program asks to enter a song, then ask the user to enter y or n for yes or no if they want enter another song. If yes then the program asks again. But then the max is fifteen songs, at the end if the user enters n or gets to fifteen the program will output "There have been blank song titles entered" where blank is is the amount of songs entered. I have been either getting no output, 0 songs entered, and/ or nothing close to the output i wanted, what is my problem?/

Comment: This looks suspiciously like either homework or a test question.

Comment: Wait, you're getting different results each time? You said `and/or`, so I'm not quite understanding your question. Could you clarify it a bit more?

Comment: You may find the following reading helpful: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In...

```
songarray[j].length();
```

...`j` has been set to 0, so it asks for the length (in characters) of the first song title, not the number of populated song titles in the array (which you're not keeping track of at all).

Suggestions:

- use a `std::vector<std::string>` for your song titles, and `push_back()` new song titles as they're read.  Then you don't need to have or worry about a limitation (15) on the number of songs your program supports.  You can also use `.size()` to tell you how many push_backs you've done.
- check the state of `std::cin` after streaming
- `std::cin >> some_std_string` will stop at the first whitespace, but real-world song title have multiple words: you should use `std::getline(std::cin, variable)`.
- consider using a blank line as the input delimiter rather than asking yes/no every time, it makes it much easier:

In all, consider putting this in the guts of your program and working from there...

```
std::vector<std::string> song_titles;
std::string next_song;
while (std::getline(std::cin, next_song) && next_song != "")
    song_titles.push_back(next_song);
```

Note: some people may prefer `!next_song.empty()` as it's more efficient, but I feel it's less expressive too.

Comment: Good points, but the point about "pass by reference" is wrong.  `songarray` is an array, which decays to a pointer when passed to the function.